# Symfony2: Add Collection via AJAX Outside of Symfony

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.7

I am attempting to pass form data through a REST API. The API is built in Symfony (2.7) and the actual data entry form lives on an external, non-symfony site. The form submits just fine until I try to pass in a pair of 'collections'.

I have been following [this tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) and thus have the following in my Type class:

```
$form->add('event', 'collection', array(
    'type' => new AvRequestEventType(),
    'allow_add' => true,
    'by_reference' => false,
));

$form->add('equipment', 'collection', array(
    'type' => new AvRequestEquipmentQuantityType(),
    'allow_add' => true,
    'by_reference' => false,
));
```

My data entry form looks like this (I will show only for the "event" collection since the "equipment" collection code is essentially the same):

```
      var eventsPrototype = '<div id="event___name__" class="row"><div class="small-8 columns"><label for="event___name___location">Location<input type="text" id="event___name___location" name="[event][__name__][location]" maxlength="100" /></label></div><div class="small-4 columns"><label for="event___name___time">Time<input type="time" id="event___name___time" name="[event][__name__][time]" /></label></div></div>';
      var $eventsHolder;
      var $addEventLink = $('<a href="#" class="add_event_link">Add Event</a>');
      var $newLinkLi = $('<li></li>').append($addEventLink);

      $eventsHolder = $('ul.events');
      $eventsHolder.append($newLinkLi);

      /*
        count the current form inputs we have (e.g. 2), use that as the new
        index when inserting a new item (e.g. 2)
      */
      $eventsHolder.data('index', $eventsHolder.find(':input').length);

      //add a new event form on page load
      addEventForm($eventsHolder, $newLinkLi);

      $addEventLink.on('click', function(event){
      event.preventDefault();

      //add a new event form
        addEventForm($eventsHolder, $newLinkLi);
      });

      function addEventForm($eventsHolder, $newLinkLi) {
        // get the new index
        var index = $eventsHolder.data('index');

        // Replace '__name__' in the prototype's HTML to
        // instead be a number based on how many items we have
        var newForm = eventsPrototype.replace(/__name__/g, index);

        // increase the index with one for the next item
        $eventsHolder.data('index', index + 1);

        // Display the form in the page in an li, before the "Add a tag" link li
        var $newFormLi = $('<li></li>').append(newForm);
            $newLinkLi.before($newFormLi);
        }
```

When it's time to submit the form, this is the AJAX call:

```js
ajaxObject = {
  url: $("#postform").attr("action"),
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
  },
  crossDomain: true,
  data: $("#postform").serialize()
};

$.ajax(ajaxObject)
  .success(function(data, status, xhr) {
    ...
  })
  .fail(function(data, status, xhr) {
    ...
  })
  .always(function(data, status, xhr) {
    ...
  });
```

Let's say I created two events. Note that an Event entity has two fields, a location and time (in "time" format"). This is a sample of what is being sent as data for those events:

```
[event][0][location]:Event A
[event][0][time]:22:22
[event][1][location]:Event B
[event][1][time]:22:11
```

Inside of my Symfony REST controller, I create a new, unnamed form to handle the submission:

```
$form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamed('', new AvRequestType(), $entity);
$form->handleRequest($request);

...validation and whatnot
```

**UPDATE:**

The production log produces the following error when trying to add the collection array:

```
"The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "array" given."
```

I know this means I have to somehow convert the collection array to a string in order for it to be accepted by Symfony. But how? I am already serializing the entire form via Javascript before passing it to Symfony. I suppose if I had a fixed number of items in the collection I could JSON.stringify() every form field but that does not seem like a very elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is that the form needs to have a name.

So instead of...

```
$form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamed('', new AvRequestType(), $entity);
```

...a name must be given...

```
$form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamed('myrequestform', new AvRequestType(), $entity);
```

This allows Symfony (I would assume anyway) to recognize all fields as belonging to the same request. So instead of having a request look like this:

```
eventDate:2016-02-01
pickupDate:2016-02-29 09:45:00
returnDate:2016-02-17 06:30:00
attendees:32
specialInstruction: special
[event][0][location]:LA
[event][0][time]:00:00
[event][1][location]:LB
[event][1][time]:11:11
```

It now looks like this:

```
avrequest[eventDate]:2016-02-01
avrequest[pickupDate]:2016-02-29 09:45:00
avrequest[returnDate]:2016-02-17 06:30:00
avrequest[attendees]:32
avrequest[specialInstruction]: sepcial
avrequest[event][0][location]:LA
avrequest[event][0][time]:00:00
avrequest[event][1][location]:LB
avrequest[event][1][time]:11:11
```

When you consider how a form within Symfony is submitted this makes sense; the name attributes of each form element are laid out in exactly the same matter.

If anybody wants to add a more elegant explanation than this, feel free.